# "Weld edges into faces" problem

Tags: modeling, edges, faces

I am trying to follow this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ajgnk5FyLrg

on exactly 0:32, when he draws an irregular outline on top of a face, then welds it into the face and extrudes, but that "weld edges into faces" operator doesn't work as expected for me. Instead of a nice face cut-in, I get chaos. The original face gets deformed, as some of its vertices move to be glued into the cutting edges.
I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.
I know I'm not supposed to manually fill the outline with a face, so I didn't.

I know existing workarounds like the knife tool, booleans or "traditional" loop cuts. I just don't like them.

Blender 3.6 here

You can check it in my Blend:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k_C8xOoksht9ODOFZSnv-DM13cfZeHmo/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: You need to merge the vertices to get a closed loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 2 vertices here are overlapping and disconnected, select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* and it will work:

[image]

Comment: Omg, I made such a basic mistake, I can't believe. Thank you!